# Can you add a checkedlistbox item with a string name and integer value at the same time?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Windows Forms application that will let you pair apprentices and journeymen. I have two checkedlistboxes for each type of employee. You can then check off who is at work for the day and press a button to sort them and output them to a third list box.

That part works fine, my main issue is assigning an integer value to each journeyman and apprentice so that L & I ratio rules are adhered to. Is there a way to assign a value to these items(employees) on the checkedlistbox so people don't get paired completely randomly?

Comment: You can add a class instance as an item, and then override the `ToString` method.

Comment: Use `Tag` property. It accepts object, so your integer will be boxed, then unbox it "on the other end" with something like `var id = item.Tag as int;`. Oh, and switch to WPF for god's sake ;) It's way faster and more compatible. DPI friendly. Think of non-standard screen users. I work on 4K. WinForms apps looks very ugly on it, because they are scaled as bitmaps.

Comment: It looks like you have a problem which you are trying to solve *"people don't get paired completely randomly"*. It will be easier to help if you demonstrate it with a code, see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear how you bind your data, so I'm making a wild guess you bind them as strings. If it is so, you may need to bind your data in a different way.

I assume you have some sort of a `Person` object, and a collection of those, say `PersonCollection` that you bind to your lists as strings.
Instead when you bind a collection to the list, place an instance of `Person` in to listitem `Tag`.

When iterate over the list of checked items, inspect `Tag`s, make (safe) casts back to `Person` object and make whatever comparisons/manipulations you need.